# Delete row in tkinter treeview with identified "cell"

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a treeview with tkitner and I made it si that you can identify a "cell" inside the treeview with a button click, I used `tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == ' cell'`.

The "cell" is identified with one button click (i have used `bind` function `<Button-1>`). I want to make a function that will delete the row (selected row), but the function does not work. It does not show any error.
I think that the problem is because even if the row is selected, its also a "cell" thats selected.

I posted a full code (even if its long) because I think that you need to see what I have done to make this

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
from tkinter import messagebox

def edit(event):

    def double(event): # funkcija koja kreira celiju kada se klikne dupli klik
        try:        
            if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'cell':
                # the user clicked on a cell

                def ok(event):
                    """Change item value."""
                    tree.set(item, column, entry.get())
                    entry.destroy()

                column = tree.identify_column(event.x)  # identify column
                item = tree.identify_row(event.y)  # identify item
                x, y, width, height = tree.bbox(item, column) 
                value = tree.set(item, column)


            elif tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'heading': 
                # the user clicked on a heading

                def ok(event):
                    """Change heading text."""
                    tree.heading(column, text=entry.get())
                    entry.destroy()

                column = tree.identify_column(event.x) # identify column
                # tree.bbox work only with items so we have to get the bbox of the heading differently
                x, y, width, _ = tree.bbox(tree.get_children('')[0], column) # get x and width (same as the one of any cell in the column)
                # get vertical coordinates (y1, y2)
                y2 = y
                # get bottom coordinate
                while tree.identify_region(event.x, y2) != 'heading':  
                    y2 -= 1
                # get top coordinate
                y1 = y2
                while tree.identify_region(event.x, y1) == 'heading':
                    y1 -= 1
                height = y2 - y1
                y = y1
                value = tree.heading(column, 'text')

            elif tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'nothing': 
                column = tree.identify_column(event.x) # identify column
                # check whether we are below the last row:
                x, y, width, height = tree.bbox(tree.get_children('')[-1], column)
                if event.y > y:

                    def ok(event):
                        """Change item value."""
                        # create item
                        item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("", ""))
                        tree.set(item, column, entry.get())
                        entry.destroy()

                    y += height
                    value = ""
                else:
                    return
            else:
                return


            # display the Entry   
            entry = ttk.Entry(tree)  # create edition entry
            entry.place(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height, anchor='nw')  # display entry on top of cell
            entry.insert(0, value)  # put former value in entry
            entry.bind('<FocusOut>', ok)  #validate when you click on other cell
            entry.focus_set()

        except IndexError:

            Error=messagebox.showinfo("Error!","You have 0 rows. Please add a new row.")
            pass

    tree.bind('<Button-1>', double) #kreiranje celije za unos i novi red sa duplim klikom


    def deleterow(event):   # funkcija za brisanje izabranog reda sa delete i backspace dugmicima
        try:
            SelectedRow= tree.selection()[0]
            tree.delete(SelectedRow)

        except IndexError: 
            Error=messagebox.showinfo("Error!","Please seleect the project that you want to delete")
            sys.exit() #za resavalje greske
            pass

        except ValueError: 
            Error=messagebox.showinfo("Error!","Please seleect the project that you want to delete")
            sys.exit() #za resavalje greske
            pass

    tree.bind("<Delete>", deleterow)
    tree.bind("<BackSpace>", deleterow)

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")                         
myApp.geometry("1900x1000")

tree = ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=20)
tree['show'] = 'headings'

sb = ttk.Scrollbar(myApp, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
sb.grid(row=1,column=12,sticky="NS")

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

tree["columns"]=("1","2")

tree.column("1", width=50)
tree.column("2", width=50)

tree.heading("1", text="Project Name")
tree.heading("2", text="Size [m2]")


item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("",))
tree.item(item, tags=item)
tree.bind('<1>', edit)

tree.grid(row=1 ,column=0,pady=5)


myApp.mainloop()
```

If I identify the "cell" with `<Double-Button-1>`, then it works because with 1 click I just identify the row, not the cell.

Is there any way you do this if I use `<Button-1>` for cell identification?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @figbeam I have done that

But Ill update the question in a bit

Comment: Does not run: `NameError: name 'tree' is not defined`. If you don't provide code that runs I'll have difficulty in reproducing your problems. By run I mean: I'll paste your code into IDLE, save and press F5. If that runs, then it runs else not. Ok.

Comment: @figbeam try now

Comment: @figbeam now it works

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @figbeam no my friend, im trying for 3 days. I cant figure out, the program does not show me any error. I think that the problem is because even if the row is selected, its also a "cell" thats selected, but I do not know how to fix that.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: It seems to work for me. I can delete selected rows. The program does have a strange structure though. I don't see why functions `double` and `deleterow` should be inside function `edit`.

Comment: @figbeam If I identify the "cell" with `<Double-Button-1>`, then it works because with 1 click I just identify the row, not the cell. I i identify the cell with  `<Button-1>`, then it does not work, and I want to identify the cell with  `<Button-1>`

Is there any way you do this if I use `<Button-1>` for cell identification?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit difficult as I have little experience with Treeview. I tried to isolate different functions and I also removed a lot of code that was unnecessary for basic understanding. I think I got a working concept but I have structured my code quite differently from yours. Have a look and see what you think:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def cell(event):
    '''Identify cell from mouse position'''
    row, col = tree.identify_row(event.y), tree.identify_column(event.x)
    pos = tree.bbox(row, col)       # Calculate positon of entry
    return row, col, pos

def single(event=None):
    '''Single click to select row and column'''
    global row, col, pos
    row, col, pos = cell(event)
    print('Select', row, col)

def ok(event=None):
    '''Validate entry as at loses focus'''
    tree.set(*item, typed.get())    # Set tree cell text
    entry.place_forget()            # Remove entry without deleting it

def double(event=None):
    '''Double click to edit cell'''
    global row, col, pos, item
    row, col, pos = cell(event)
    print('Edit', row, col)
    item = row, col                 # Remember which item you are editing
    typed.set(tree.set(row, col))   # Set entry text
    x, y, w, h = pos                # Place entry on tree
    entry.place(x=x, y=y, width=w, height=h, anchor='nw')
    entry.focus_set()               # Set focus in entry

def deleterow(event):
    '''Delete selected row'''
    print('delete', len(tree.selection()))
    if len(tree.selection()) != 0:
        row = tree.selection()[0]
    try:
        print('deleterow', row)
        tree.delete(row)
    except:
        print('no row selected')


myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")                         
myApp.geometry("600x600+800+50")

tree = ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=20)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
sb = ttk.Scrollbar(myApp, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
sb.grid(row=1,column=12,sticky="NS")
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
tree["columns"]=("1","2")
tree.column("1", width=150)
tree.column("2", width=150)
tree.grid(row=1 ,column=0,pady=5)

tree.heading("1", text="Project Name")
tree.heading("2", text="Size [m2]")

item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("Project Alice","500 GB"))
tree.item(item, tags=item)

# Mouse & keyboard bindings
tree.bind('<1>', single)
tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', double)
tree.bind("<Delete>", deleterow)

# Create entry in global scope
typed = StringVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(tree, textvariable=typed)
entry.bind('<FocusOut>', ok)

myApp.mainloop()
```

I have kept console printouts in the code so it's easier to see what is going on. I use globals to keep track of important variables. My choices of variable names could have been better...

Anyway, with this code I can select any row/column with singele or double click. Delete row seems to work just fine. I have not any function for adding new rows but that should not be difficult.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what im looking for. In your code, It shows error when I click on any other "cell", i cant create new rows, I cant edit names of the column names.
Also, I do not want to double click to create a cell, I want to make it with one click.

The code that I posted works perfectly when I set the program to create an entry/cell with a double click (the everything works), but it does not work when I want to create a cell with a single/one click.